# fillRect() doesn't apply on stroke()

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have the following code:

```
socket.on('render', function(data) {

world.fromJSON(data);
me.fromJSON(world.getPlayerById(me.id));

// Drawing:
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,world.WIDTH, world.HEIGHT);


camX = clamp(me.x - $canvas.width()/2, 0, world.WIDTH - $canvas.width());
camY = clamp(me.y - $canvas.height()/2, 0, world.HEIGHT - $canvas.height());

ctx.save();
ctx.translate( -camX, -camY );


background.draw(world.WIDTH, world.HEIGHT, ctx);

world.render(ctx);
ctx.restore();

});
```

and background which looks like this:

```
var Background = function() {

  this.image;

this.draw = function(WIDTH, HEIGHT, ctx) {
    var p = 20;
for (var x = 0; x <= WIDTH; x += 40) {
     ctx.moveTo(0.5 + x + p, p);
     ctx.lineTo(0.5 + x + p, HEIGHT + p);
 }


 for (var x = 0; x <= HEIGHT; x += 40) {
     ctx.moveTo(p, 0.5 + x + p);
     ctx.lineTo(WIDTH + p, 0.5 + x + p);
 }

 ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
 ctx.stroke();
}

}
```

The problem is that strokes are not overdrawn with the following:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,world.WIDTH, world.HEIGHT);
```

I don't know what could cause the problem, but it's very annoying.

and it looks like this
[image: wrong]

any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: By overdrawn, do you mean that your fillRect doesn't go over the top of the stroke lines?

Comment: You're also missing `ctx.beginPath()` and `ctx.closePath()` when drawing lines.

Comment: You were right, it's fixed, thank you very much :)